# Websocket.ononpen Runs before Websocket is actually open

Tags: javascript, websocket

In my `socket.onopen` function there's a line that says `socket.send(nickname)`, but for some reason I am getting an error - `Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.`

Here's my code and screenshot of an error:

```
// создать подключение
var socket = null;
var nickname;

// отправить сообщение из формы publish
document.forms.publish.onsubmit = function() {
  var outgoingMessage = this.message.value;
  socket.send(outgoingMessage);
  return false;
};

const connect = document.getElementById('connect');
const disconnect = document.getElementById('disconnect');

connect.addEventListener('click', function(){
    start();
});

function start() {
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081");

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        var incomingMessage = event.data;
        showMessage(incomingMessage);
    };

    socket.onopen = authorizate();
}

function authorizate(){
    nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').value;
    document.getElementById('nickname').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('subm').style.display = "inline-block";
    disconnect.style.display = "inline-block";
    connect.style.display = "none";
    console.log(nickname);
    socket.send(nickname);
}
```

[image: error image]

Comment: Should be `socket.onopen = authorizate;` — your code is *calling* that function and assigning the return value to `onopen`

Comment: @Pointy Oh gosh, I am so inconsiderate, sorry. Thank you!